# OpenCV module error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I've tried a lot but I am not able to figure out what went wrong.
I install OpenCV wheel package from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

When I import cv2 it works too but when I call the imread function it is not detecting. Looked up everywhere but i couldnt find any solution. Kindly help me

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Vineeth/Downloads/test.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

And the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vineeth/Desktop/programs/Python/cv2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\Desktop\programs\Python\cv2.py", line 7, in <module>
    img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Vineeth/Downloads/test.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'
```

It doesn't work in pycharm and not even in IDLE

When i try to uninstall the package via pip it returns error like this

```
C:\Users\Vineeth>pip uninstall cv2
Cannot uninstall requirement cv2, not installed
```

When i try pip search cv2 , It returns like this

```
C:\Users\Vineeth>pip search cv2
aircv (1.4.5)      - Find object position based on python-opencv2.
cv2 (1.0)          - My Blog Distribution Utilities
cv2-wrapper (0.1)  - Wrapper for python opencv 2.4.12 32bit
cv2wrap (1.0)      - Wrapper for python opencv 2.4.12 32bit
pyElphel (0.1)     - Use Elphel camera from python with opencv2
```

Comment: you edited the post following my answer, but now the stacktrace does not match your code.

Comment: This was the real error , Sorry the old was just a mistake

Comment: see my edited answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call your program `cv2.py` or you override the *real* `cv2` module.

Comment: No no look at this.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vineeth/Desktop/programs/Python/cv2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\Desktop\programs\Python\cv2.py", line 7, in <module>
    img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Vineeth/Downloads/test.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'

Comment: I've made the changes but still it says the same

Comment: Because it shows me like this .  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vineeth/Desktop/programs/Python/trail.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\Desktop\programs\Python\cv2.py", line 7, in <module>
    img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Vineeth/Downloads/test.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'

Comment: Deleting the old cv2.py worked for me , Thank you very much sir

Comment: I will mark the answer after the 5 min cooldown. Sorry for a silly question

Comment: that's a classic :)